# use Azure Blob storage encryption without keyvault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

In a BtoB application, I want to encrypt data transparently in Azure Blob storage.

However, we cannot store the keys in keyvault:
We will generate a symmetric key and use it to encrypt data in blob storage.
This symmetric key will then be encrypted using the public key of the customer and stored somewhere.
If a decryption is needed, the customer will decrypt the symmetric key using his private key.

All the samples that we have found are using keyvault to store the keys.
The most relevant sample is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/client-side-encryption?tabs=dotnet#blob-service-encryption.

This doc says: Your key and key resolver instances, either through Azure Key Vault SDK or an external implementation.
But no documentation explains how to do the "external implementation"
I tried this code for generating the KeyEncryptionKey:

```
 var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(_context.EncryptionKey);
 var jsonWebKey = JsonWebKeyConverter.ConvertFromSymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricSecurityKey);
 jsonWebKey.AdditionalData["iv"] = Convert.ToBase64String(_context.IV);               
 string jsonSerializedKey = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWebKey);
 Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.JsonWebKey keyvaultKey = (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.JsonWebKey)JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.JsonWebKey>(jsonSerializedKey);
 keyvaultKey.KeyType = KeyType.Rsa;
 var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(keyvaultKey);
 var keyResolver = new KeyResolver(new DefaultAzureCredential());
 

 // We want the key to be passed from 
 ClientSideEncryptionOptions encryptionOptions = new ClientSideEncryptionOptions(ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V2_0)
 {
    KeyEncryptionKey = cryptoClient,
    KeyResolver = keyResolver,
    // String value that the client library will use when calling IKeyEncryptionKey.WrapKey()
    KeyWrapAlgorithm = "RSA-OAEP"
   };
```

It compiles, but at execution time, the call to _rootContainer.UploadBlobAsync(fullPath, stream)  raises this error:
Operation WrapKey is not supported with the given key

Apparently, it tries to encrypt or decrypt the symmetric key.
If I don't specify KeyWrapAlgorithm, it returns:
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'KeyWrapAlgorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if it's relevant depending on your actual scenario, but you do write "If a decryption is needed, the customer will decrypt the symetric key using his private key." which seems to imply that it's not data that is used continuously. So here's a suggestion that doesn't really answer your exact question, but proposes an alternate path to achieve much of the same result with much less code for you to write!

I am the original author of AxCrypt, a fairly well-known file encryption app. Recently I published a command line toolbox, that I think supports your scenario as far as the encryption/decryption goes. It uses the same core encryption code as AxCrypt, that has been proven over the years, using sound and well tried algorithms and modes of operation. It can generate asymmetric key pairs (RSA-4096), wrap the private key securely as you describe, and use the public key to encrypt a symmetric key that is used in encrypting the data. It won't actually use the Azure client encryption library, but the net effect will be pretty much the same. An encrypted blob in Azure, that can be decrypted using a private key.

It's a command line utility that can be called by scripts or C#/.NET code, and has an extensive set of features. You can find it at github at https://github.com/xecrets/xecrets-file-cli licensed under GNU GPL v3. Although the CLI wrapper is recently published the underlying cryptography has been in production for over 7 years, and used extensively so it can be regarded as stable and solid. There are complete examples in the documentation, including pretty much your scenario.

You can of course also link directly with the underlying library just like the CLI does - but then your code will be affected by the GPL requirement that your code also becomes GPL. If you use the CLI as-is this is not an issue, only the CLI is and remains GPL:ed.

As a side benefit, if the blob is downloaded as a file, it can be decrypted manually on the command line using the CLI on Windows, macOS and Linux, or using a desktop app (we're soon releasing one, it's in beta right now), and even the existing AxCrypt, which can be a benefit for your customers if they do require to decrypt it themselves.

If for whatever reason you really need to use the Azure library, then this suggestion is not relevant of course.